# Regular Expression PHP Phone Number

Tags: php, regex

I am making a regular expression that will read phone numbers from a PHP form. I have the expression most of the way completed. It needs to read a phone number in any of the following formats:

> ```
> 623-456-7890
>
> 456-7890
>
> 6234567890
>
> 4567890
>
> 623.456.7890
>
> 456.7890
>
> 623 456 7890
>
> 456 7890
> ```

The expression I have made at this point is the following:

```
(([0-9]{3}){0,1})((\W){0,1})([0-9]{3})((\W){0,1})([0-9]{4})
```

It mostly works, the only phone number it doesn't read is the third one in the above list `(6234567890)`. What would I have to add or change to make it read that phone number?

Comment: Remove all non-digits, check the number of digits and reformat it anyway you want.

Comment: I would, but I actually need the regular expression to be able to include all of those characters for this form. I would love to strip em, but I can't.

Comment: Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/. There's even a PHP port ~ https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php

Comment: You could always strip them and then add them back in a consistent manner.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input and https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Answer (score 2):

That's much better:

```
([0-9]{3})?\W*([0-9]{3})\W*([0-9]{4})
```

Comment: `([0-9]{3})*` is too greedy... needs to be `([0-9]{3})?`

Answer (score 1):

`/(?:[\(]?\d{3}[\)\.\- ]?)?\d{3}[\.\- ]?\d{4}/`

Here it is in practice: http://regex101.com/r/pL3dB0/3

Comment: This also matches `-------`

Comment: It also matches non-phone numbers.

Comment: Now this allows literal parenthesis (not in the question).

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ So you are telling me that someone who is RegEx'ing for phone numbers doesn't want phone numbers that look like this: `(777)777-7777`? You know the question doesn't specifically say it wants phone numbers that contain a "1" either, should I exclude those as well.

Answer (score 1):

Real phone numbers are much more complicated than this because of exchanges and so forth. This will match numbers, periods and hyphens, not all are required, but it also doesn't check for valid phone numbers.

```
([0-9]{3})?[ .-]?([0-9]{3})[ .-]?([0-9]{4})
```

Comment: Contains 3 capturing patterns (not in the question)